# Why are Rust documentation tests not executed in Docker when cross-compiling to musl?

Tags: docker, rust

My documentation tests are silently not executed in my Docker environment while everything works on both Windows and Ubuntu/Debian hosts.

I created a minimal [Github Repository](https://github.com/arturh85/cargo-test-doc-docker/tree/9a459485e7f2ac5cc95894cea4d8a32f65cb6c6f) to demonstrate the issue. I tried two different versions of Rust nightly and Rust stable, debug/release, all without success. See my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/arturh85/cargo-test-doc-docker/blob/9a459485e7f2ac5cc95894cea4d8a32f65cb6c6f/Dockerfile) and [complete build output](https://github.com/arturh85/cargo-test-doc-docker/blob/9a459485e7f2ac5cc95894cea4d8a32f65cb6c6f/build-output.txt).

Example code:

````
/// Fixes string arrays which can also be objects into string arrays
/// # Examples
///
/// ```
/// assert_eq!(cargo_test_doc_docker::add(1, 2), 3);
/// ```
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}
````

Result when executing on Debian:

```
arturh@host:~/projects/cargo-test-doc-docker$ cargo test
   Compiling cargo-test-doc-docker v0.1.0 (/home/arturh/projects/cargo-test-doc-docker)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.39s
     Running target/debug/deps/cargo_test_doc_docker-9d5ae146cd4c3628

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

     Running target/debug/deps/cargo_test_doc_docker-2a696d2579128ce1

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

   Doc-tests cargo-test-doc-docker

running 1 test
test src/lib.rs - add (line 4) ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

The problem occurs when executing the build on Docker. This is a minimal Dockerfile that reproduces the problem:

```
FROM ekidd/rust-musl-builder:nightly-2020-01-26-openssl11 as build
COPY --chown=rust:rust . .
RUN cargo test; echo $?
```

Result for every Rust toolchain I tried:

```
Step 6/17 : RUN cargo test; echo $?
 ---> Running in b266fc72f3c1
   Compiling cargo-test-doc-docker v0.1.0 (/home/rust/src)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.32s
     Running target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/deps/cargo_test_doc_docker-7b40e7e5b47f49eb

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

     Running target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/deps/cargo_test_doc_docker-0bfec9752a7bec14

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

0
```

It does not even try to execute any doc tests and exits with zero so it's not easily noticed. I guess it must be something the [Docker base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ekidd/rust-musl-builder/dockerfile) does, but what could that be?

Comment: You appear to be cross-compiling in your Docker container, but not when compiling locally. What other differences exist?

Comment: I included a minimal Dockerfile to reproduce the issue, and the only differences should be that I use Debian while the ekidd/rust-musl-builder Base image is itself based on Ubuntu plus the library setup stuff the Docker image does. But 
 I don't see how those could make rust ignore my unit tests.

Comment: BTW: I use ekidd/rust-musl-builder because I have a dependency on hyper/openssl and could not get it to work other than statically linking openssl with this target. At least that is what I could understand ...

Comment: The **musl** image [cross-compiles to musl by default](https://github.com/emk/rust-musl-builder/blob/441e6222bb0fd621a1be947201f5b10fab92e6e7/cargo-config.toml#L2-L3). Are you saying that your Linux system *also* cross-compiles by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cross Compilation

This is a logical, if surprising, outcome of cross-compilation.

To understand why, imagine that you:

- Compile on a Linux x64 machine (Host).
- Target a Windows ARM machine.

The generated code cannot be executed on the current host (Linux x64): it is prepared for a different CPU (instruction set) and OS (system calls).

Since the tests -- unit tests, integration tests, and documentation tests -- are also generated for the target architecture, they cannot be executed on the host either.

---

#### What to do with the tests?

If your code has no specific dependency on a specific platform, then you can content yourself with compiling for the host and running those.

Otherwise, you will need access to a machine that can actually run the cross-compiled binaries. You can still use cross-compilation to speed up building those binaries, and then upload them to either a physical or virtual machine to run them.

AFAIK Cargo does not help with the latter, so you'll need your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

[Shepmaster was right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288020/why-are-rust-documentation-tests-not-executed-in-docker#comment106643692_60288020), when I target the x86_64-unknown-linux-musl it also does not work locally on Debian:

```
arturh@host:~/projects/cargo-test-doc-docker$ cargo test --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl; echo $?
   Compiling cargo-test-doc-docker v0.1.0 (/home/arturh/projects/cargo-test-doc-docker)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.28s
     Running target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/deps/cargo_test_doc_docker-8dfff5631875d404

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

     Running target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/deps/cargo_test_doc_docker-eb877250b708174b

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out

0
```

I guess I must have a separate build step for testing the doc tests with the target `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.